# Java regex for anything inside double ** example: **text**

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I need the regex for this case scenario:

```
**This text is bold** this is not **abc123*-#$%&/()** this is not **yes****
```

So I can have these results separated:

```
This text is bold
abc123*-#$%&/()
yes**
```

I have been struggling with this for hours, help.

The most close I have been is this:

```
\*\*([^\*]\*)\*\*
```

Actually, I need to use `*` inside `**here(*)**` in order to obtain `here(*)`.

I wanna obtain `123?=)*` result from `**123?=)***`.

Comment: is this `**This text is bold** this is not **abc123*-#$%&/()** this is not **yes****` the input?

Comment: yes it is the text I need to separate, I need everything inside double **.

Comment: what have you tried the hours you have been struggling? share some code maybe?

Comment: done: this is the closest I have been to the solution \*\*([^*])\*\* but this wont allow me to use * inside the souble asteriks.

Comment: You may use `\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)\*\*`, see https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/2.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew but this wont allow me to do this: \*\*123\*"#$%(\*\* so I can have this result: 123*"#$%(

Comment: Would it not be easier to write a simple parser instead of doing everything with a regex.  Basically it seems like all you want is the text between unshared `**` delimiters.  And I don't believe returning `yes**` from `**yes****` would be realistic in a string where  `**yes****no**` should probably return `yes` and `no`

Comment: @WJS thank you, do you have any example I can follow? What I really want to do is to remove one \* only if the \* belongs to this structure \*\*anything\*\*

Comment: No idea what you mean, see https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we are so close, a \* on the middle is accepted, I only need this scenario to work: regular expresion: \*\*anything\*123\*\*\* the last \* is not on the result: https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/4

Comment: This is now not clear, try `\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*\**)\*\*`, https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/5

Comment: `\*\*.*?\*\*(?!\*)`, i.e. start matching at `**`, and end match at `**` that is not followed by another `*`, matching reluctantly between them, so it won't match `**` in the middle. See demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G2D7Rc/1). --- Prefix with `(?s)` if you want that match across linebreaks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you this works! you all are amazing!!

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, you are a genious, this works perfectly, I'lll check your explanation to try to undestand, Thank you all you are amazing!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*\**)\*\*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/5).

An equivalent is `(?s)\*\*(.*?)\*\*(?!\*)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJisRh/6) (based on [Andreas suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65099222/java-regex-for-anything-inside-double-example-text?noredirect=1#comment115090688_65099222)). However, this pattern is about 1/3 slower than the previous one.

**Details**

- `\*\*` - a `**` substring
- `([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*\**)` -  Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `*` (`[^*]*`) that are followed with zero or more repetitions of a `*` that is not immediately followed with `*` (see `\*(?!\*)`) and then zero or more non-asterisk chars, and then any amount of asterisks (see the `\**` at the end of the group pattern)
- `\*\*` - a `**` substring

The `(?s)\*\*(.*?)\*\*(?!\*)` is similar, the `(?s)` is a DOTALL inline modifier that makes a `.` match across lines, and then `(.*?)` matches and captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of `**` text that is not immmediately followed with `*`.

Comment: Thank you, now I know more about regex than yesterday!